# Addition of quantum optical Hamiltonians (e.g. beamsplitter + squeezer)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-optics

The Hamiltonians corresponding to beamsplitter and squeezing operators are respectively:
\begin{align}
H &= ab^\dagger + a^\dagger b \: (\text{beamsplitter}) \qquad H = a^\dagger b^\dagger + a b \: (\text{squeezer})
\end{align}
Usually when considering the evolution of the modes $a, b$ undergoing respective beamsplitter and squeezer unitaries, we would successively apply $U_\text{BS}$ and then $U_\text{S}$ (in the Heisenberg picture) to obtain the input-output transformations. What if we have a composition of the two Hamiltonians,
\begin{align}
H &= ( ab^\dagger + a^\dagger b) + ( a^\dagger b^\dagger + a b ) 
\end{align}
Is there a physical interpretation for the resulting interaction between the modes?

Alternatively, is there a straightforward operator ordering theorem that can split the resulting unitary
\begin{align}
U = \exp\Big[ ( ab^\dagger + a^\dagger b ) + (a^\dagger b^\dagger+ ab ) \Big]
\end{align}
into a succession of unitaries? I know there are general theorems for splitting exponential operators for specific algebras that the operators satisfy (e.g. Appendix 5 of Barnett and Radmore), but not sure how to generalise them to the present case.